# QML Extension Plugin

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qqmlapplicationengine

How do we use the dll file created by QML Extension Plugins?
[The link regarding dll file creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-qmlextensionplugins-example.html), doesn't give enough information about how do we exactly use the dll file in other projects (Qt Quick applications).

A simple example on this with step by step explaination would be helpful.

Comment: There are tons of examples in Qt documentation itself about plugin creations. [one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html), [two](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html). A plugin aimed to expand the capabilities of QML that do not exist in it. Anyway it depends on what exactly you going to do. [Here](https://github.com/qml-box2d/qml-box2d), for example, one of my projects - plugin for implementing 2d physics in QML.